# How to get function return value and use it in html template, flask

Tags: python, flask

I have html file index.html and a python file using flask, i want to call a function from python file and use the return value in an attribute in html i.e.

```
<div style="display: {{ some_builtin_function('drowsiness_alert') }};" >
    <h1>Hide this</h1>
</div>
```

python file:

```
@app.route('/drowsiness_alert')
def drowsiness_alert():
    return "none"
```

I am using url_for to return url from flask so i was wondering if there is a builtin method for getting function return value, i have searched the internet for a while but the information is too overwhelming, i am new to flask. example code of url_for is

```
<img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" height="80%">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define a function to be called from a jinja2 template, it is necessary to define it inside a python file and add it as a global variable of the jinja environment. Then you can call them with the associated name.

In my example, the element is shown if the current time is between 12pm and 4pm, otherwise it is hidden.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template
)
from datetime import datetime, time

# Define the function.
def drowsiness_alert():
    t1,t2 = time(12,0,0),time(16,0,0)
    return 'block' if t1 <= datetime.now().time() <= t2  else 'none'

app = Flask(__name__)

# Add the function by name to the jinja environment.
app.jinja_env.globals.update(drowsiness_alert=drowsiness_alert)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

```html
<!-- Calling the function. -->
<div style="display: {{ drowsiness_alert() }}">
    <p>Your content here.</p>
</div>
```

---

You can also use a global variable inside the defined function. The example below shows you how.

```
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    redirect, 
    render_template, 
    url_for
)

display_alert = False

def drowsiness_alert():
    return 'block' if display_alert else 'none'

app = Flask(__name__)

app.jinja_env.globals.update(drowsiness_alert=drowsiness_alert)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/toggle-alert')
def toggle_alert():
    global display_alert
    display_alert = not display_alert
    return redirect(url_for('.index'))
```

I wonder why you don't just pass your variable to the template and use a simple if-else condition here.

Comment: instead of using time i use a global variable display_alert, when i change the value of my global variable to 1 html does not update. Initially global var is 0 so display=none but after global var becomes 1 the element is still disply:none

Comment: @Saad I have revised my answer. Without knowing your code, I assume that you assigned a new value to a local instead of the global variable. I hope your goals are fulfilled and I would be happy if you click the tick.